# Javascript Post Request to different host

Tags: javascript, post, xmlhttprequest, request

I want to send a POST request via JavaScript to a different host with some request headers and a post body.

How can I do this?

I tried it with XMLHttpRequest, but I get the following error: 
`0x80004005 (NS_ERROR_FAILURE)`

```
var xmlHttpRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlHttpRequest.open("POST", "https://somedomain/deviceapi/v1/rest/registration/device/anonymous", false);
xmlHttpRequest.setRequestHeader("Accept", "application/json");
xmlHttpRequest.setRequestHeader("some key", "some value");
xmlHttpRequest.setRequestHeader("Accept-Charset", "UTF-8");
xmlHttpRequest.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8");
xmlHttpRequest.send("some data");
```

Comment: You can't, it's forbidden for security reasons, see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy)

Comment: you can use a from to POST anywhere...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`cd C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\
chrome.exe --allow-file-access-from-files --disable-web-security 
pause`

This allows you to circumvent the same origin policy in google chrome and test your stuff.

Answer (score 0):

Not possible with XHR unless your browser supports CORS and the remote host allows your origin (or allows all origins (*)). See [here](http://www.nczonline.net/blog/2010/05/25/cross-domain-ajax-with-cross-origin-resource-sharing/).

This function from [html5rocks.com](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/cors/) will let you know:

```
function createCORSRequest(method, url) {
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  if ("withCredentials" in xhr) {

    // Check if the XMLHttpRequest object has a "withCredentials" property.
    // "withCredentials" only exists on XMLHTTPRequest2 objects.
    xhr.open(method, url, true);

  } else if (typeof XDomainRequest != "undefined") {

    // Otherwise, check if XDomainRequest.
    // XDomainRequest only exists in IE, and is IE's way of making CORS requests.
    xhr = new XDomainRequest();
    xhr.open(method, url);

  } else {

    // Otherwise, CORS is not supported by the browser.
    xhr = null;

  }
  return xhr;
}

var xhr = createCORSRequest('GET', url);
if (!xhr) {
  throw new Error('CORS not supported');
}
```

Comment: I am using ff22, so it does support CORS. How can I figure out if the remote host allows origin?

Comment: It is working. CORS is supported, but I don't get any response.